# Getting first character of double percentage variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm doing a for loop in a batch file to set environment variables based on properties from a file, for example like this:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in (%APPDIR%\config.properties) do (
    set %%G=%%H
)
```

I'd like to do the `SET` only if `%%G` doesn't start with `#` (being a comment), however I can't seem to apply the "substring" technique `%var:~0,1%` with `%%G` as input. How can I do a `if` check based on the first character in `%%G`?

I'm guessing I might have missed something obvious (and I'm not quite understanding the `%%`-variable concept).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had read the help or reference information for `FOR` you should have seen `EOL`, which although it says 'End Of Line' really only refers to one end, the beginning!

```bat
For /F "EOL=# UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims==" %%G In ("%APPDIR%\config.properties"
) Do Set "%%G=%%H"
```

So the above reads any line not beginning with `#` i.e. it ignores your commented lines, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I experienced some trouble at first, but it was a bug on my side. More valid answers around, but this solved it most simply for my case.

Comment: Simpler: `for /F "eol=# usebackq delims=" %%G in ("%APPDIR%\config.properties") do set "%%G"`

Comment: Correct, and both methods have to assume that the properties file does not use any spaces before the initial `=` otherwise any variables used further in the script may not be work as anticipated!

Answer (score 2):

In *batch*, the string substitution is performed on variables: [[SS64]: Variable Edit/Replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).
So, in order to make that work, the content of `%%G` has to be assigned to some (temporary) variable and then work with that.
But, since there's a [[SS64] FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop involved, the *Delayed Expansion* ([[SS64] EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); typing `set /?` in *cmd*, will offer information about this topic as well) has to be taken into consideration.

Given all the above, here's your code slightly modified:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in (%APPDIR%\config.properties) do (
    set _VAR_NAME=%%G
    if "!_VAR_NAME:~0,1!" neq "#" (
        set !_VAR_NAME!=%%H
    )
)
:: Remove/comment the line below, as its only purpose is showcasing the result
set
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cannot do so directly (according to my knowledge at the point in time where I wrote it; Compo's accepted answer actually disproves this misbelief!)! You will need to pass it to another variable first.

Long answer with the code and more explanation:

By putting the variable value in another variable with the usual percentage signs on each side, you can get the in the way you described in your question.
To make this accessible in the loop though, you will need to use DelayedExpansion which will give you the value "at runtime" in a loop in batch.
To use it, you will need to add the following line above the loop:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

And instead of percentage signs around the variable name use exclamation marks: `!varname!`

So this should work:

```bat
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ("%APPDIR%\config.properties") do (
    set helper=%%G
    set helper=!helper:~0,1!
REM from here on helper contains the first char from %%G; you can access it with !helper!
REM set %%G=!helper!
)
```

Further I am unsure if you can or want to actually set `%%G` so I used another variable which you need anyways instead. If you want you can include the commented line by removing the `REM`

Comment: What makes my answer so bad one should downvote? If there is anything I am missing or wrong information, feel free to correct me :) I am not perfect and would like to learn from my mistakes... I cannot see any major differences to CristiFati's answer either...

Comment: From my point of view a solid answer and +1ed. Only difference to accepted answer is `EOL` in loop solved it more simply for me.

Comment: @geisterfurz007, perhaps rewording your answer to eradicate its' first line, _which my short answer disproves_, may prevent possible down votes!

Comment: @Compo Fair point! I was actually not aware of the way you who in your answer. I reworded the question to keep it close to my previous one still. I dislike erasing mistakes one made completely. Thanks for the hint

Comment: That said, you would also need to fix the incorrect assignment `!helper~0:1!`, but then again they're looking at ignoring any `%%G` which begins with `#` and you are manipulating `%%H`.

Comment: Indeed; I was just taking note of the code in the question and missed important detail

Comment: Your assignment `!helper~0:1!` is still wrong, use the assignment in @CristiFati's answer for a clue!

Comment: Apparently I am unable to copy something from the question properly; thanks for the eye out!

Comment: I'm not even going to ask what happens if the unknown value of `%APPDIR%` contains a space…but would ask you to reflect on your initial complaint against your down vote, to see if it may have been justified just not explained!

Comment: I never said it was not justified. As said I would like to learn from my mistakes. But it really does bother me that downvotes are just left commented. Yes there are flaws but if for example you downvoted and told me there are many of them in there I would not complain. Just leaving it uncommented though renders me clueless and wondering what was so bad (as I initially wrote). That should not have been a complaint either but a request for improvement suggestions or reasons why it should be removed entirely.

Comment: Ordinarily, I'd expect that a down vote would focus the author to thoroughly check and verify what they'd posted before asking why. You responded initially with `I cannot see any major differences to CristiFati's answer`, which means you were either not focused on reviewing it or you failed to review it before asking why. I've highlighted some rather important points which meant your code definitely didn't answer the question and since then you've made another edit which again makes your code fail. I agree that the down vote should have been followed up except if it came from @CristiFati!

Comment: I just downvoted this answer for these reasons: **1.** The `for` command does not work as written. It seems you copied the quotes from @Compo's answer, but you forgot to also copy the `usebackq` option. **2.** This answer does not solve the request, that is: _"I'd like to do the `SET` only if `%%G` doesn't start with `#`"_; you need an `if` command to do that... Yes, I know these are minor mistakes, but I was moved to downvote after read your comments about _"any major differences to CristiFati's answer"_ and your complaints about previous downvote, and still didn't fixed your answer! **`:(`**

Comment: 1. Is indeed justified. For 2. The questions title as well as the question in the body ask how to get or how to do something with the first character of a double percent variable. This should as well be sufficiently answered in my answer. Note to the comment: I did not want to scan every character from their answer and I could not see a any difference in explanation which was what I meant (might have been easily misunderstandable). Thank you for your explanation; loop should be fixed. (Finally understand usebackq now as well; thanks!)